Angular binding not working when the CSS class is nested within an ::ng-deep block
I want to conditionally add a class to my element. This is my css file:
::ng-deep .a {
&.b{
background-color: red;
}
//other  styles
}

When I add
<div class="a b">
I can see the classes applied but when I modify this to accept conditional class
<div class="a" [class.b]="true">
I cannot see class b applied.
I have tried modifying this to use [ngClass], still no luck.

issue not reproducible -> stackblitz

Why would you use ::ng-deep on a div? you can simply put background-color: red !important;

no need to add ::ng-deep just use scss
